# How to handle recurring svg and can I add and remove the child svg using "mouseover" and "mouseout"?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
'''      
         #Parent svg
         svg.append('g')
            .selectAll("dot")
            .data(storage)
            .join("circle")
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.x); })
            .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.y); })
            .attr("r", .5)
            .style("fill", "green")
            .on("mouseover", function (e, d) {
                d3.select(this).transition()
                   .duration(200)
                div.style("left", (e.pageX) + "px")
                    .style("top", (e.pageY - 28) + "px");
                console.log(e, d);
                div.transition()
                    .duration(500)
                    .style("opacity", 0);
                div.transition()
                    .duration(200)
                    .style("opacity", .9);
                div.html(
                    'X, Y: ' + d.x + ", "+ d.y +
                    "<br>Pin: " + d.pinName + 
                    "<br>Net: " + d.netName);

                   s_data = storage.filter(a => a.netName ===d.netName);
              
                #Child svg
                svg.append('g')
                   .selectAll("dot")
                   .data(s_data)
                   .join("circle")
                   .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.x); })
                   .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.y); })
                   .attr("r", .5)
                   .style("fill", "red")
            
               
            })

            .on('mouseout', function(d,i){
                d3.select(this).transition()
                    .duration('200')
                    .style('fill', 'green');
            })
```

'''

Initially all dots are green when I mouseover any one of the dots, the set of dots with common netName will highlight, after this I can't go back to normal, i,e I want all dots to be green again so that I can highlight other dots and check for there grouping. The data is basically a JSON object

[image]

Comment: Do you need to add new red dots ? Maybe you could just update the color of the existing dots. If you have a unique key for each dot then you can retrieve the update selection corresponding to your filtered data and change the color in the mouseover and mouseout functions.

Comment: Yes I do have key for all dots, my question is how to get hold of all the dots with same key? I mean consider some n number of dots have key A , others have key B , how to highlight only A dots?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example: `https://codepen.io/ccasenove/pen/RwyzZrV`

I have a unique `id` key on each dot and a `netId` attribute shared by some dots. If you specify a key function when you bind the data to a d3 selection, then you can obtain a sub selection of dots with the same netId like this:

```
const _data = data.filter(da => da.netId == d.netId);
svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(_data, d => d.id)
  .style("fill", "red")
```

the d3 `data` function will return the update selection, i.e. dots that already exist with the ids in the filtered data. So you can change the color of this update selection in `mouseover` and `mouseout` functions.

Comment: But I have to use only netId and I don't have id for the dots. My data is like,
"""
data = [ { netId : "A", x: 1,y:1}, {netId: "B", x:2,y:2}, {netId:"C", x:3, y:3}, .... ] 
"""
I can only use netId to filter data, but after filtering also the code is grouping wrong dots.

Comment: I think, I can add 'id' to my data, yes now it is working.
Thank you Cedric Casenove : )

Comment: You're welcome @SouravBM. The id can simply be a concatenation of x and y for example. Please accept the answer if it helped you !